# Undefined symbols for architecture i386: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CkoCsv"

Tags: ios, objective-c, csv, export-to-csv, chilkat

I am Developing `iPad` App in my app `read` and `write` `csv` File.

`csv` file read and write for using `Chilkat` library  but I am getting this error.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CkoCsv", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in backGroundViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

How can resolve this problem ?

Please Help me.

thanks

Comment: Library is only build for device, not for simulator.Check in device.

Comment: The library has not been added properly, please let us know how you added that library?

Comment: I am try in device but same problem..

Comment: i was check but here properly added library...

Comment: @Niraj: Were you able to read the csv file using the Chilkat library?

Answer (score 1):

Check `Chilkat` library info.Check with `terminal`

```
 lipo -info library(drag library to here).
```

I think library not build for `simulator.If` you have the source code built it for simulator also.For further verification check with `real` `device`.

Comment: Normalythis kind of errors happened becoz of mismatched library build.Then check with the library added currently, check library search path and u import the library to the view controller too..

Comment: I was check library search path and Build Phases here is currently added. but same problem here...

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Chilkat support forum](http://www.chilkatforum.com/) by searching.  I found [this](http://www.chilkatforum.com/questions/255/ios-link-error-missing-required-architecture-i386) instantly:

> This happens if you are trying to link your simulator build against
>   the device static lib. Chilkat provides two separate static libs for
>   IOS apps. One targets the actual IPhone/IPad device and the other is
>   for the simulator. Both libs are named "libchilkatIos.a". After
>   unzipping, the simulator version will be located in the "libSimulator"
>   directory, and the device version will be located in the "libDevice"
>   directory.
>
> When building for the simulator, make sure to use the simulator lib.
>   When building for the device, make sure to use the device lib.
>
> It is easy to create a single universal lib using libtool. For
>   information about this, see
>   http://www.chilkatsoft.com/chilkatIos.asp

Comment: I am using this file libchilkatIos.a but I am getting same error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import "libchilkatIos.a" file to your project. Just right click on any class file, Add files to-> and then select "libchilkatIos.a" file from lib->i386 folder in your Chilkat directory. Now the error will go away.